# How to display the variable declared in a class

Tags: c#, xamarin

I created a class called `Weather` as below:

```
public class Weather
{
    public string WeatherName { get; set; }
    public int WeatherId { get; set; }
}
```

And then, I would like to get the data from an URL and display the data I've got.

```
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetWeather();
    }

    async public void GetWeather()
    {
        string url = "the URL....";

        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        string result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

        var resultObject = JObject.Parse(result);
        int WeatherId = (int)resultObject["icon"][0]; //get the "icon" data from the JSON file
        Weather weather = new Weather();
        weather.WeatherId = WeatherId;
        switch (WeatherId)
        {
            //setting the WeatherName according to the WeatherId...
        }
    }
    
}
```

I would like to display the `WeatherId` and the `WeatherName`, but I have no idea how to do that. Please give me a simple solution as I may not understand some difficult codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your page, add some UI elements to display the data

```
// these go inside of the page's Content tags
<StackLayout>
  <Label x:Name="WeatherIDLabel" />
  <Label x:Name="WeatherNameLabel" />
</StackLayout>
```

then in your code when you retrieve the data

```
WeatherIDLabel.Text = weather.WeatherId;
WeatherNameLabel.Text = weather.WeatherName;
```

there are thousands of excellent tutorials, videos, sample apps, etc that illustrate how to build an app from scratch.  I suggest you take the time to walk through some of them

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! The solution works!! I watched some of the tutorials but I can't find a suitable one for my situation. I should try watching some more tutorials for beginners lol. Thanks a lot anyway!!